# Power function for Neyman-Pearson best test

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

**Question**

I have a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ of Bernoulli$(\theta)$ random variables. Let the size of a test of a simple null $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ against a simple alternative $H_1:\theta=\theta_1$ be $\alpha$. I found that the critical region for the test with maximum power has the form $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \geq c_\alpha$ for some constant $c_\alpha$, by Neyman-Pearson.

I am not sure how to find the power function for this test, and the question actually doesn't ask for it, instead it asks for the approximate power function - ie for large samples. It says to show that the approximate power function $w(\theta)$ of the above test is given by

$w(\theta)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{\theta_0 -\theta}{\sigma(\theta)}+\frac{\sigma(\theta_0)}{\sigma(\theta)}z_\alpha\right) $

where $\Phi$ is the cdf for the standard normal, $\Phi(z_\alpha)=1-\alpha$ and $\sigma(\theta) = [\theta(1 − \theta)/n]^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

**My ideas**

I'm sure that from the normal cdf there must be an application of the Central Limit Theorem somewhere but I've been stuck on this for ages. Any help would be appreciated.